# Which Threejs exporter should I use to export a model that can be loaded with a BufferGeometryLoader?

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I tried to load 3d models that have been exported via 3dmax exporter with BufferGeometryLoader but it throws this error "Cannot read property 'index' of undefined", I tried to export the same model with blender exporter and the same happened.
How should i export a model to be able to load it using BufferGeometryLoader?

Comment: Just curious, why do you specifically want to use BufferGeometryLoader if it's giving you trouble? There are many other loaders that create `THREE.BufferGeometry`, too.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy i need to load my model creating BufferGeometry instead of Geometry, what other loaders can i use and how to use it to create BufferGeometry?

Comment: [Most three.js loaders](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=BufferGeometry++repo%3Amrdoob%2Fthree.js+path%3A%2Fexamples%2Fjs%2Floaders%2F&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) now create `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry` :)  `OBJLoader` is a good bet. I also suggest GLTF2Loader and the [glTF Blender exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter).

Comment: @DonMcCurdy okay i got it, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code of `BufferGeometryLoader` it looks like it can load the following format -

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4

Look at the following maxscripts. This could be used to export to the aforementioned geometry format -

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/max